# What do I have to consider when modifying 'wss_minimaltrust.config'?

Tags: permissions, configuration, sql

I have an [issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98607/how-to-deploy-an-eventreceiver-which-writes-to-sql-server-correctly/98733#98733) which makes me go mad for quite a while. It probably has to do with permissions and CAS. In the referenced question I explained that I tried out a number of approaches, running against walls over and over again.

Now it seems that the last option I (the internet) can think of is to modify the 'wss_minimaltrust.config'. Here I would simply add a SecurityClass node:

```
<SecurityClass Name="SqlClientPermission" Description="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

Plus an IPermission node:

```
<IPermission class="SqlClientPermission" version="1" Unrestricted="true"/>
```

The machine where SharePoint and its 14-Hive is located on is a productive server. Several hundred users are posting requests to it via SharePoint 24/7.

So I wonder are there any aspects I have to consider when modifying this file?

1. I was told that modifying 'web.config' would need an IIS restart to apply changes. Is it the same for 'wss_minimaltrust.config'?
2. Can I simply open and modify the xml-file via 'Visual Studio' or Notepad or do I have to
   use some other tool? Or maybe there are just some settings i can change using SharePoint-Designer?
3. Are there any other aspects I have to consider when messing around with this file?

I am pretty sure that this approach will solve my issue but I'm kind of afraid to modify .config files on a running system. Because if I screw the running system the axe will swing.

Comment: Do you really need to modify the existing _minimum? Can't you do a custom permission level, or modify the web.config to allow your code to use a different trust level? See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583158%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: @RobertLindgren there is a node in web.config with Typename="SqlDataSource" and Safe="False". Spontaneously I would set it to "true", but I two problems here. (1) Like I mentioned before as far as I know this would need the IIS service to restart, which is not an option. (2) I have to admit modifying this node would rather be a guess as I would be not really sure about what I am doing :)

Comment: Pretty sure you would need an IISRESET even for modifying _minimum though?